# How to take the integral of this expression

Tags: calculus

let $v''=w$

$$w=ce^{-t}\frac{1}{2-t}$$

Find v.

($c$ is a constant). I couldn't move any pencil, need your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robert Israel already gave the answer.

If you consider $$v''=\frac{c\,e^{-t}}{2-t}$$ you have $$v'=c \int \frac{e^{-t}}{2-t}\,dt=\frac c {e^2}\int\frac{e^{2-t}}{2-t}\,dt$$ Let $x=2-t$ to get $$v'=-\frac c {e^2}\int\frac{e^{x}}{x}\,dx=-\frac c {e^2}\,\text{Ei}(x)+C$$ where you see appearing the exponential integral which is a special function.

The next integration will be much more difficult and the series solution, as Robert Israel proposed, looks to be the most reasonable solution (for the time being).

Answer (score 1):

This function does not have elementary antiderivatives. If you want the answer in "closed form", you must use special functions: the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Alternatively, you could write the solution as a series, converging for $|t|<2$:

$$a + bt+{\frac {c}{4}}{t}^{2}-{\frac {c}{24}}{t}^{3}+{\frac {c}{96}}{t}^{4
}-{\frac {c}{960}}{t}^{5}+{\frac {c}{2880}}{t}^{6}+{\frac {c}{40320}}{
t}^{7}+\ldots $$

where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary constants.